# How to get inetd and warp to work together

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-warp

I am trying to get inetd to work with warp.

Currently, I have

```
main = do
  s <- mySocket 0
  s' <- getSocketName s'
  runSettingsConnection settings ((, s') <$> socketConnection settings s) app
```

which will return some data if there but it consumes all cpu and system memory.

Is there a way to get this to work properly and to close when all connections are closed?